# Karaf Drools Camel Kafka Development environment debugging

Tags: eclipse, apache-camel, drools, apache-karaf

I have a karaf bundle using Drools, Kafka and camel.

I can run it using EIK and set breakpoints on the java code.
How can i set breakpoints and debug the Drools rules?

Can Pax Exam be used for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EIK ... is not very well supported right now. 
But Pax Exam works well, debugging works with it also. 
As of the current state (Pax-Exam 4.6) you need to attach to the Pax-Exam Karaf container via remote debugging. Starting with Pax Exam 4.7 (not released right now) it's possible to run karaf as "embedded" container in Pax-Exam so a debugging will work there.

Answer (score 0):

See the Drools documentation> Section 20.2. Hello World contains a short introduction on how to debug DRL code.